# how to change semantic-ui default 16 column count to 24

Tags: semantic-ui

I tried to put a "@columnCount: 24;" in src/site/globals/site.variables and execute "gulp build" but it turns out there is nothing changed.

Another doubt is even if this works, can I use something like "twenty wide column" for my page elements?

Answer (score 0):

Directly from the [Semantic UI](http://1.semantic-ui.com/collections/grid.html) website :

> All grid systems use an arbitrary column count. Semantic's default theme assumes 16 columns. This number can be adjusted in your project by adjust the `@columnCount` value in `site.variables`.

Answer (score 0):

The @columnCount variable can only go up to 16.

Since Semantic-UI was built with a 16 column default, all the other related variables and calculations are based off that. In order to go higher than 16 columns you'll have to find the appropriate places and add the necessary variables, calculations, and classes in order to make it work.

However, there are a couple of easier ways that I think you could accomplish what you're looking for.

First, rather than adding in more columns, you might be able to accomplish what you're looking for by changing the margins and paddings of the appropriate elements or possibly by using the "relaxed" or "very relaxed" classes.

But if you absolutely need that many columns, then try using [nested grids](https://semantic-ui.com/collections/grid.html#column-widths).

Something like this perhaps:

```
<div class="ui two column grid">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="ui ten column grid">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="ui ten column grid">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```